# Can't get Java2D to render a simple line to a Graphics object

Tags: java, swing, drawing, java-2d

Because I want to invoke different classes's drawing method and draw different graphs on the JPanel so I need to take the drawing plate(JPanel or something) as an argument, passing it to my drawing method.(But I don't know if I can do that or not.... The case here is another try...)

Here is my part of the implementation.

I create a class class_diagram as follows:

```
public class class_diagram extends Object
{

private final int width = 60;  
private final int height = 80; 
private final int first_separate_line_distance= 30; 
private final int second_separate_line_distance= 55;
private int left_up_x = 0;
private int left_up_y = 0; 

public void setLeft_up(int left_up_x,int left_up_y) 
{
    this.left_up_x = left_up_x;
    this.left_up_y = left_up_y;
}


//private Graphics to_draw ;
//private JPanel place_to_draw; 

public class_diagram()
{
     // instance variable "point to" the reference which was passed in.  
}

@Override
//the parameters stands for the left-up point's coordinate. 
public void draw(Graphics to_draw) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Call draw method?\n");
    to_draw.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    to_draw.drawLine(31, 41, 131, 768);     
}

}
```

The above the is the class definition and its' drawing method.

And in the another class:

I call the draw method, and it indeed be invoked, because 
 System.out.println("Call draw method?\n"); in that draw method shows the message to me.

Nevertheless!!! The drawing on my JPanel... It wore me out.
 Because I have tried at least 4-5 methods....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class UML_Editor_13 extends JFrame {

private Edit_panel canvas = new Edit_panel();

public static void main(String[] args) {                    

UML_Editor_13 frame = new UML_Editor_13();

frame.setVisible(true);

Graphics m= frame.canvas.getGraphics();                 

Object n = new class_diagram();

n.draw(m);

}
}
```

1. Please somebody tell me why this line  "Graphics m= frame.canvas.getGraphics();" 
   doesn't work... If m references to the canvas, why

   to_draw.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   to_draw.drawLine(31, 41, 131, 768); //didn't work...?
2. Any other method to satisfy my requirements:

" invoke different classes's drawing method and draw different graphs on the JPanel so I need to take the drawing plate(JPanel or something) as an argument, passing it to my drawing method."

Comment: Do you get anything on the screen at all, or does it remain blank? Is your JPanel already black, or grey, or what color is its background?

Comment: The color of the JPanel's background doesn't change anymore.
It remains white.... T - T.

Like nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the panel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. In the method call `super.paintComponent(g)` and then your `draw()` method.

Comment: But as I want to invoke the draw method, I just write:
    Graphics m= frame.canvas.getGraphics();                 

    Object n = new class_diagram();

    n.draw(m);
Could you just please describe more specifically?
What should I write within  "paintComponent(Graphics g)"
and What should be in "draw"?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?
What should I write within the "paintComponent(Graphics g)"?
And the real drawing operation based on "draw()"?

Comment: +1, YOu should NOT use the getGraphics() method of a components. The painting is only temporary. The next time Swing determines a component needs to be repainted the painting will be lost. That is why painting is done in the paintComponent() method.